# Typescript not reading the correct type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have this React hook:

```js
import { ChangeEvent, RefObject, useEffect, useState } from "react";

type OriginalOnchange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
type OnchangeEvent = ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>;
export type OnChangeWrapper = (originalOnchange?: OriginalOnchange) => (onchangeEvent: OnchangeEvent) => void;

export const useTrackValidity = (
  inputRef: RefObject<HTMLInputElement | undefined>,
  value: string,
  invalidInputMessage?: string
) => {
  const [isValid, setIsValid] = useState<boolean>();

  const onChangeWrapper: OnChangeWrapper = (originalOnchange?: OriginalOnchange) => (onChangeEvent: OnchangeEvent) => {
    setIsValid(!(!!invalidInputMessage || !onChangeEvent.currentTarget.validity.valid));
    if (!!originalOnchange) {
      originalOnchange(onChangeEvent);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (inputRef.current) {
      inputRef.current.setCustomValidity(invalidInputMessage || "");
      setIsValid(!(!!invalidInputMessage || !inputRef.current.validity.valid));
    }
  }, [inputRef, invalidInputMessage, value]);

  return [isValid, onChangeWrapper];
};
```

When I call it like this:

```js
 const [isValid, onChangeWrapper] = useTrackValidity(inputRef, value?.toString() ?? "", invalidInputMessage);

  return (
    <StyledInput
      ref={inputRef}
      type={inputType || type}
      name={inputName || name}
      required={isRequired || required}
      onChange={onChangeWrapper(onChange)}
      onBlur={onChangeWrapper()}
      isValid={isValid}
      value={value}
      {...props}
    />
  );
```

I get this error:

```
TS2349: This expression is not callable.
  Not all constituents of type 'boolean | OnChangeWrapper' are callable.
    Type 'false' has no call signatures. TS2722: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.
```

whenever I call `onChangeWrapper`.

When I change the above to this:

```js
const [isValid, onChangeWrapper] = useTrackValidity(inputRef, value?.toString() ?? "", invalidInputMessage) as [
    boolean | undefined,
    OnChangeWrapper
  ];
```

It does work, which strikes me as odd because I basically reiterated the return type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript infers that the returned array will be `Array<boolean|yourfunctiontype>` — that is, that **all** elements will be the intersection of those types. `boolean` isn't callable, so you can't call any of the elements without some kind of guard.

To solve it, tell TypeScript that your hook function returns `[boolean, yourFunctionType]`, specifically:

```
type onChangeWrapperType = /*...the function type here...*/;

// ...

export const useTrackValidity = (
  // ...
): [boolean, onChangeWrapperType] => {
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− here
    // ...
    const onChangeWrapper: onChangeWrapperType = /*...*/;
    // ...
    return [isVaild, onChangeWrapper];
};
```